# How to pass the domain name into the reseller club api url (searching records)

Tags: php, google-reseller-api

How to pass the domain name into the reseller club api url (searching records). I need to pass the dynamic domain name value to the URL

https://httpapi.com/api/dns/manage/search-records.json?auth-userid=xxxxxxx&api-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&domain-name=novulusindia.com&type=A&no-of-records=10&page-no=1

Please suggest any solution for this

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)